# I'm AS3 developer and I want to start developing apps for Facebook. What to start with?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api

As easy as it sounds. Need advises (on books, resources etc.).

Comment: I think that if you want to create an Facebook app, you need a VALID facebook accout to create your app, which is nothing more than a website, embeded via iframe into facebook. So you also need a Website, which includes all the facebook js stuff. That is explained on the developer page of facebook. With this "canvas-page" you have got a sandbox to start with and all the facebook-functions you need in your app are an result of "ajaxing" of your page and facebook. Just have a look at the developerpages of facebook. (ExternalInterface can be used to call the FB-javascript-methods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to rolling your own External Interface calls, there is this helper api, which at least used to be supported by both Facebook and Adobe: http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

Once you've got this, you need to add the [Facebook developers app](https://developers.facebook.com/) to your FB account and there are instructions on that page covering the different types of app you might want to build.

Aside from specific calls you may want to make to the Facebook API to share or like or whatever, you are otherwise just developing a normal AS3 application (web, AIR desktop, or AIR mobile), there are no special requirements or restrictions, but if you are building a canvas app to sit on Facebook itself, you may want to think about the dimensions before you begin, and make allowance for a certain amount of FB chrome.

In terms of books, Packt have one published last year which is specifically tailored to the subject: [Flash Facebook Cookbook](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781849690720).

Most of the samples in other books and tutorials are for JavaScript, which is of course quite similar to AS, and the API mentioned above follows the form of the JS SDK closely, so you should find it quite straightforward to translate samples from JS to AS. Be advised that the Facebook API has undergone significant development in the last 18 months, and continues to develop rapidly, so samples and tutorials can quickly become out of date.